# Date "1 month ago" not working in AIX

Tags: shell-script, aix

In machine A (running Oracle Linux Server release 6.4), I am able to get the date of 1 month ago intelligently by using the following command:

```
$(date -d"1 month ago" '+%Y0%m')
```

But it is not working in machine B(AIX), is there an alternative way to achieve this? Both are in `.sh` files and run with:

```
sh Test.sh
```

Error shown in machine B:

```
date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]
```

Comment: When you say, not working in `ksh`, do you mean, not working on the same machine that the `sh` solution works on, when using `ksh` or do you mean not working on another machine entirely which has `ksh` as the default shell.  If it's two machines, are they running the same Linux / UNIX OS?  Can you provide more detail.

Comment: hi, i already re-edited my question, yes is different machine OS

Comment: i put .sh as file extension and deployed to both machine A and machine B, works for machine A but not machine B

Comment: What is the output from `oslevel -r` on the AIX box? Recent versions have ksh93.

Answer (score 13):

It has nothing to do with the shell, but with the `date` command. The `-d` option is specific to the GNU implementation of the `date` command. On non-GNU systems, that won't work unless you install the GNU version of `date` as a separate package (that would probably be installed as `gdate` or as `/opt/gnu/bin/date`...).

Note that recent versions of ksh93 have a similar feature with their `printf` builtin command:

```
printf '%(%Y%m)T\n' '1 month ago'
```

(see also `zsh` for another shell with builtin date manipulation support (`strftime` builtin in the `zsh/datetime` module)).

Some other `date` implementations also have features to adjust dates. For instance, with BSD `date`, you could do:

```
date -v -1m +%Y%m
```

I'm not aware that AIX comes with a command that does date calculation and there is no command in the POSIX toolchest, so no standard/portable command for that. You could revert to `perl` or do the calculation by hand:

```
eval "$(date +'y=%Y m=%m')"
m=$((${m#0} - 1))
[ "$m" -gt 0 ] || m=12 y=$((y - 1)) # January case
printf '%d%02d\n' "$y" "$m"
```

Comment: I've always ended up reverting to Perl on AIX for this very reason.  OP could also compile GNU date on AIX if they have the relevant build tools (a challenge in its own right).

Comment: Just found a post from 2002 on another site suggesting manipulating TZ on AIX before calling date.  `TZ=GMT24BST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/02; date` to get yesterday's date - seems a little overkill though.  I don't have access to an AIX box any more to test if that works, and if it works for large offsets (like a year).

Comment: Or /opt/freeware/bin ?

Answer (score 2):

`date -d...` doesn't work in AIX/ksh, so please use this below one, which works perfectly on AIX:

```
TZ=aaa$(expr $(expr `TZ=aaa24 date +%d` + 1) \* 24) date +%m
```