# Today's and yesterday's hardware error output from an AIX errpt log

Tags: logs, date, aix

I'm looking for today's and yesterday's hardware error output from errpt in AIX using a shell script. 
I am getting output but need to grep only date.

e.g

```
tdy=`date +'%m/%d'`
etdy=`date +'%m%d%%y'`
ydy=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%m%d`
awk '{if ($2 ~ "'^$etdy'" && $4 == "H") print $0}' /tmp/errptoutput.txt > /tmp/errptoutput1.txt
awk '{if ($2 ~ "'^$ydy'" && $4 == "H") print $0}' /tmp/errptoutput.txt >> /tmp/errptoutput1.txt

====cat /tmp/errptoutput.txt
DC32143C   0709073116 P H ent8           PING TO REMOTE HOST FAILED
6169289D   0731073116 P H ent8           PING TO REMOTE HOST FAILED
DC32143C   0801073116 P H ent8           PING TO REMOTE HOST FAILED
========================================================================
```

So I need to `grep` only date with year (without hours or minutes) .

Suppose the Hardware date is `0801073116` in errpt.

Output required using above script based on `%d%m%y` 080116 (only date) not hours and minutes.

What do I need to modify in the above script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's an edge case for using GMT+24 in the date calculation ([date math on AIX is hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265951/date-1-month-ago-not-working-in-aix)), but here's a minimal adaptation of your script that generates strings for awk to use for pattern matching today's date and yesterday's date in the [mmddhhmmyy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/errpt.htm) format that AIX errpt uses:

```
tdy=`date +'%m%d'`
tdyy=`date +%y`
ydy=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%m%d`
ydyy=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%y`
today="${tdy}....${tdyy}"
yesterday="${ydy}....${ydyy}"

awk -v today="$today" -v yesterday="$yesterday" \
  '$2 ~ today || $2 ~ yesterday' /tmp/errptoutput.txt > /tmp/errptoutput1.txt
```

One typo-fix that I noticed was in:

```
etdy=`date +'%m%d%%y'`
```

where you had an extra `%`. I also changed the format of the `tdy` and `etdy` date strings so that they only outputted the month and day. My other additions were to gather today's year and yesterday's year, then to assign `today` and `yesterday` variables using the month/day values from before, periods for the regular expression to match any character in those positions, then the years.

I see that you're parsing an existing output file, but you may also be interested in the `-s` and `-e` flags to `errpt`, which tell errpt to output only entries in the given date range, for example:

```
errpt -s 0731000016 -e 0801000016
```

Would show any errpt entries starting on July 31st of 2016 and ending on August 1st of 2016. To additionally limit the output to Hardware errors, use the `d` flag:

```
errpt -s 0731000016 -e 0801000016 -d H
```

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/errpt.htm or your local man page for more details.